# Convert struct_time gives me ".%fZ" at the end instead of the timezone and the microseconds

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

needed to convert with a specific format the following `struct_time`:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=16, tm_hour=0, tm_min=14, tm_sec=9, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=47, tm_isdst=0)
```

And I've tried to convert it to string as follow:

```
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fZ",date)
```

But for some reason, a part of the converted date still have a `.%fZ` at the end:

> 2020-02-16 00:14:09.%fZ

I assume the timezone isn't available, but how to resolve it anyway to set a timezone if it isn't available?

**EDIT**:

My pattern was wrong, it should be instead:

```
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z",date)
```

Which gives me:

> 2020-02-24 16:53:04.%f+0000

However, I still have an issue with `%f`, and I've tried to solve it by adding microseconds to the original datetime, without any effect:

```
date = date + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=000000)
```

Any idea?

Comment: According to [`time.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=strftime#time.strftime), there is no `%f` directive and `Z` would be a literal.  There is a `%Z` directive, but you aren't trying to use it.  According to [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#strftime-strptime-behavior), there is a `%f` directive (for microseconds) and a `%Z` directive (but you aren't trying to use that).  However, that doesn't appear to be the variant of `strftime()` that you're using.

Comment: Strange, as there is actually a `%f` for microseconds. However, I agree that there is an error in my pattern: it should be `%Z`, not `Z`. Anyway there is no microseconds here, which is anoying. I've updated my question